# how to get the total of the earnings

Tags: php, mysql

the code is expected to calculate the total amount of the "Net Earning" row. How do i write a code to do that. The `$stmt` variable is associated to a query from the database

```
<div class="block-card-body">
    <div class="my-table table-responsive">
        <table class="table align-items-center table-flush mb-0">
            <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th>Order ID</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Fee</th>
                <th>Net Earning</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            
            <tbody>
                
            <tr>
<?php 
foreach ($stmt as $val) {
?>
                <td><a href="#" class="order-id"><?php echo $val['PAY_ID']; ?></a></td>
                <td class="text-color">$<?php echo $val['PAY_AMOUNT']; ?></td>
                <td class="text-danger">$<?php echo ($val['PAY_AMOUNT']) * 0.1 ; ?></td>
                <td class="text-success">$<?php echo $val['PAY_AMOUNT'] - (($val['PAY_AMOUNT']) * 0.1) ; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $val['PAY_DATE']; ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php 
} 
?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div><!-- end block-card-body -->
```

Comment: A quick look at [How to format code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) may help you with your next question

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable to use as an accumulator, initialise it to zero.

Then in the loop, calulate the net and add it to your accumulator. How you display it is up to you later.

Also note, I moved the `<tr>` inside the loop so you get a well formed table row

```
            
            <tbody>
<?php 
$netTotal = 0;
foreach ($stmt as $val) {
?>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#" class="order-id"><?php echo $val['PAY_ID']; ?></a></td>
                <td class="text-color">$<?php echo $val['PAY_AMOUNT']; ?></td>
                <td class="text-danger">$<?php echo ($val['PAY_AMOUNT']) * 0.1 ; ?></td>
<?php
$t = $val['PAY_AMOUNT'] - (($val['PAY_AMOUNT']) * 0.1);
$netTotal += $t;
?>
                <td class="text-success">$<?php echo $t;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $val['PAY_DATE']; ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php 
} 
?>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: This is the right answer ;)